# What is logout and [Process Completed] that is printed when a python script runs?

Tags: python, scripting

I have an executable Python script, and I have it to setup to open in a terminal.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def main():

    print "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__": main( )
```

Why is logout and [Process Completed] printed after the Hello World. I would like to have the terminal just print "Hello World" even without pwd and exit. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: logout from current tty session, dont use exit

Comment: how do i do that? i tried killing the parent using os.getppid(). that escapes the logout. but i still need to close the terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X's Terminal leaves the shell open after exit, by default. Go to Settings > Profiles > [your profile] > Shell and change "When the shell exits:" to "Close if the shell exited cleanly" (or "Close the window", if you prefer).

To leave the shell up without displaying anything, you could call `raw_input()` at the end of `main()`. Then pressing Enter will exit. But you still need to change the setting as described above, or the window will print the extra bits you don't want and remain open.

Comment: thank you. that works. but more importantly i would like to know how to keep the other text from displaying.

Comment: is there a way to kill the tty session from inside python. i would prefer that than change the setting.